# How to run multiple instances of console app with VS2019?

Tags: c++

I am following networking tutorial series and I need to run both Server and Client projects. When I click ServerProject->Debug->Start New Instance everything is fine, but the option becomes unavailable for ClientProject while Server is running. How can I enable this option and run them both? There is also a third project with winsock stuff set as Startup Project and both Server and Client depend on it.

Comment: Start another instance of visual studio, and do the same. If you don't need to run a 2nd instance in debug mode, just open a CMD shell and run the `.exe` from there.

Comment: Usually the client and the server are separate executable and you can configure the debugger to debug both if you need. Or you could run one and debug the other. It all depends on what you want to debug.